# mysql changing delimiter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to add this function using php myadmin, first off I get on error line 5, which is apparently because you need to change the delimiter from ; to something else so i tried this

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN (s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
      BEGIN


    etc....

      END

DELIMITER ;
```

But I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter |
```

Please help !?

Comment: I don't think you need this outside of the CLI...

Comment: It doesn't work with or without it. 

If I don't change the delimiter i get an error on line 5 where the first delimiter is.

Unfortunatley I don't have access to the console

Answer (score 1):

solved it by installing new version of phpmyadmin, which has a delimiter box!